# How to save mlr3 resample object results to disk

Tags: r, machine-learning, serialization, mlr3, resample

Has anyone an efficient way to serialize and save the R6 class objects produced by the `resample()` function in the `mlr3` package? Using `saveRDS()` doesn't seem to work as it takes forever. Googling suggested that serialization of the R6 objects in the problem. I saw a post from 2020 that points out this issue but doesn't seem solve it (https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/482). So i'm wondering if anyone managed to efficiently save these objects, especially when `store_models=T` for the learners?

Please see some sample code below. I don't have the task object defined, but i'm assuming any task will do.

```
glmnetBasic <- lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type = "prob", predict_sets=c("train","test"))
glmnetAT = auto_tuner(
  method = tnr("random_search", batch_size = 4L),
  learner = glmnetBasic,
  resampling =  rsmp("cv", folds = 5),
  search_space = lts("classif.glmnet.default"),
  measure = msr("classif.bacc"),
  terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 100L), store_models=T)

outer_resampling = rsmp("subsampling", repeats = 100, ratio = 0.8)

future::plan(list("multisession", "sequential"))
time1 <- Sys.time(); set.seed(796343)
rr1= resample(task1, glmnetAT , resampling=outer_resampling, store_models = TRUE)
Sys.time() - time1

saveRDS(rr1, "fileName.rds")
```